# Pydantic (BaseModel) - How to mock (pytest/unittest/mockito)?

Tags: mockito, pytest, python-unittest, pydantic, python-unittest.mock

I'm doing unit tests (using pytest/unittest/mockito, basically) and I need to mock the instantiation of a class implemented using Pydantic (BaseModel). Apparently it's not possible to mock a class in these circumstances without passing effectively valid data. I can't use "ANY()", because errors occur. Is there any way to mock this class without having to use valid data as arguments?

NOTE: Apparently the problem occurs because Pydantic is being used.

I've been doing a lot of research on the Internet, but no luck  ... Any ideas?

Below are the codes I'm using in my tests in a very simplified way...

**pydantic_class.py** - Pydantic (BaseModel) Class

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from some.path.sometypea import SomeTypeA
from some.path.sometypeb import SomeTypeB


class PydanticBaseModel(BaseModel):
    someInt: int
    someStr: str
    someTypeA: SomeTypeA
    someTypeB: SomeTypeB
```

**code_to_test.py** - Code to Test

```
from some.path.pydantic_class import PydanticBaseModel


class ClassToTest():
    def test_method(self)
        pydantic_base_model = PydanticBaseModel(
            someInt=0,
            someStr="value",
            someTypeA=<SomeTypeAObj>,
            someTypeB=<SomeTypeBObj>
        )
        [...]
```

**test_code.py** - Test Code

```
import unittest
from mockito import ANY, when


class SomeTypeTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_sometype_method(self):
        when(PydanticBaseModel(
            someInt=ANY(),
            someStr=ANY(),
            someTypeA=ANY(),
            someTypeB=ANY()
        )).thenReturn(None)
        [...]
```

Test Output (Simplified)

```
(test-project) [username@username-pc test-project]$ pytest -sv ./test_code.py
=================================================================== test session starts ====================================================================

[...]

_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

>   ???
E   pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 4 validation errors for PydanticBaseModel
E   someInt
E     value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
E   someStr
E     str type expected (type=type_error.str)
E   someTypeA
E     value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
E   someTypeA
E     value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)

pydantic/main.py:338: ValidationError
================================================================= short test summary info ==================================================================
FAILED test_code.py::SimulacaoComboTest::test_sometype_method - pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 2 validat...
==================================================================== 1 failed in 0.94s =====================================================================
```

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `mockito`, but you look like you're misusing both `when`, which is used for [monkey-patching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5626250/147356) objects, and `ANY()`, which is meant for *testing* values, not for assignment.

The [mockito walk-through](https://mockito-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/walk-through.html#the-walk-through) shows how to use the `when` function. You use that when you need to mock out some functionality.

The `ANY` function is a matcher: it's used to match e.g. arguments in function calls.

Here's an example of both of those in action:

If you want `os.path.exists` to always return `True`, regardless of the path, you can call:

```
>>> when(os.path).exists(ANY).thenReturn(True)
>>> os.path.exists("/path/example")
True
>>> os.path.exists("/another/example")
True
```

Here, `ANY` in the argument list matches **any** argument, so `os.path.exists` will return `True` regardless of how we call it.

If we only wanted it to return `True` for a specific path, we would have written instead:

```
>>> when(os.path).exists(ANY).thenReturn(True)
>>> when(os.path).exists("/another/example").thenReturn(True)
>>> os.path.exists("/path/example")
False
>>> os.path.exists('/another/example')
True
```

---

For what you're doing, you don't appear to need either one of these constructs. If you want to test "when I create a `PydanticBaseModel`, the object returned has the same values I used when constructing it", then you could write:

```
import unittest

from model import PydanticBaseModel, SomeTypeA, SomeTypeB


class SomeTypeTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_sometype_method(self):
        expectedTypeA = SomeTypeA()
        expectedTypeB = SomeTypeB()

        expected = {
            "someInt": 0,
            "someStr": "",
            "someTypeA": expectedTypeA,
            "someTypeB": expectedTypeB,
        }

        model = PydanticBaseModel(
            someInt=0,
            someStr="",
            someTypeA=expectedTypeA,
            someTypeB=expectedTypeB,
        )

        assert model.dict() == expected
```

Comment: Dude, that wasn't an explanation, it was a lesson  ! What if I simply want to bypass the execution of "PydanticBaseModel", so that its call doesn't throw errors? That is, I don't care that "PydanticBaseModel" is executed, only that it does not generate errors in its execution in the test scenario. 

Comment: If you don't care about the value, just call `PydanticBaseModel(...)` without assigning the value to anything and without `assert`-ing anything. Either the test will pass (the function completes without errors), or it will raise an exception, causing the test to fail.

Comment: Note that I added `.thenReturn(None)` in the call to "PydanticBaseModel" (test_code.py) to better explain what I want. That is, I don't want this class to be instantiated, because the parameters for it in the call are invalid. I just need the "instance" to return "None". 

Answer (score 1):

Ok, friends!

I found 3 different approaches to mock the instantiation (construction) of a **Pydantic** (*BaseModel*) class.

**NOTE:** I don't know if these are the best ways to approach the problem or even if they are correct. So I ask you to comment!

**APPROACH 1 (The best in my view  )**

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock


class SomeTypeTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch("some.path.pydantic_class.PydanticBaseModel.__init__")
    def test_sometype_method(self, pydantic_base_model):
        pydantic_base_model.return_value = None
        <SOME_PATCH_DEPENDENT_CODE>
        [...]
```

**APPROACH 2**

```
import unittest

from unittest.mock import patch
from some.path.pydantic_class import PydanticBaseModel

class SomeTypeTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_sometype_method(self):
        with patch.object(PydanticBaseModel, "__init__", return_value=None):
            <SOME_PATCH_DEPENDENT_CODE>

        [...]
```

**APPROACH 3**

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch


class SomeTypeTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_sometype_method(self):
        patcher = patch("some.path.pydantic_class.PydanticBaseModel.__init__", return_value=None)
        patcher.start()
        self.addCleanup(patcher.stop)
        <SOME_PATCH_DEPENDENT_CODE>
        [...]
```

**NOTE:** With "addCleanup" you no longer need to keep a reference to the patcher object.
Ref(s).: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-methods-start-and-stop

---

**PLUS:** I continue to insist that the **Mockito** approach...

```
when(PydanticBaseModel).thenReturn(None)
```

... fails because the "PydanticBaseModel" class uses **Pydantic** (*BaseModel*), which seems to be something Mockito is not able to handle.

---

**Thanks!**

---

**UPDATE (20220613.2232):** While all the answers "effectively" manage to mock the classes, **PROBABLY THE CORRECT ANSWER IS THIS**...

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from some.path.pydantic_class import PydanticBaseModel


class SomeTypeTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_sometype_method(self):
        patcher = patch("some.path.pydantic_class.PydanticBaseModel.__new__", return_value=PydanticBaseModel(**{<INITIALIZATION_DICT_CONTENT>}))
        patcher.start()
        self.addCleanup(patcher.stop)
        <SOME_PATCH_DEPENDENT_CODE>
        [...]
```

... **because this way we can define, under our control, a class instance return** (and not just "None").

**NOTE:** Note that we now use `__new__` instead of `__init__`. For that reason, this is probably the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

A Pydantic model attribute can also be mocked by using a `unittest.mock.patch` with autospec, e.g. in pytest with decorator syntax:

```py
from model import PydanticBaseModel
from unittest import mock


class TestPydanticBaseModel:

    @mock.patch('model.SomeTypeA', autospec=True)
    def test_with_some_type_a(self, mock_type_a):
        PydanticBaseModel(someTypeA=mock_type_a)
        mock_type_a.some_method.assert_called()
```